# JQuery post function problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I try to post some data via json objects to my asp.net mvc view, here is the code

```
$("#submitButton").click(function () {
               var name = $("#name")[0].valueOf();
               var price = $("#price").valueOf();
               var url = $("#url").valueOf();

               var product = { Name: name, Price: price, Url: url };
                   $.post("/Home/NewProduct", product, function (json) { $('ul.items').append("<li><img src=" + url + "/></li>"); },"json");

           });
```

and now, the result is an error:

uncaught exception: [Exception... "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object"  nsresult: "0x8057000c (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:1804/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js :: f :: line 132"  data: no]

I try JQuery 1.4.1 and 1.4.2, If I try this code the error is the same

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/Home/NewProduct",
     dataType: "json",
     data: { Name: name, Price: price, Url: url },
     success: function () { $('ul.items').append("<li><img src=" + url + "/></li>"); }
               });
```

What I'm doing wrong? Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: looks like visual studios code completion is the guilty culprit here!  i hate it when it turns my .val to .valueOf !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value of an input type element, use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of [`.valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf), like this:

```
var name = $("#name").val(),
    price = $("#price").val(),
    url = $("#url").val();
```

When you call `.valueOf()` on a jQuery object, it gets an array of DOM elements...and that doesn't serialize well :)

Answer (score 0):

In your $.post call if you pass JSON as a 4th parameter then jQuery will expect `VALID json string` only other wise it might cause error.

example of valid JSON is

```
var json = {"a":"my name", "b":"my school"};
```